# How to get the values of a dynamically created table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object

[image]

The above screenshot shows the actual correct form. For getting this I tried the below code. My `<td>` contains a heading as well as a subpoint, which are added dynamically. On click of the **Submit** button, I want to read the heading & subpoint corresponding to that heading. The data format is given below.

I'm adding the rows dynamically with the header and the data respectively. I'm trying to gather the data in an object before sending the data to the server via AJAX. I'm not able to read the data in the given format.

## HTML CODE

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h4>Scorecard Metrics</h4>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="button-bar">
<button class="btnn btnn--pill add-point">Add Sub-Point</button>
<button class="btnn btnn--pill add-heading">Add Heading</button>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
<table id="table-scorecard_co" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 100px!important;" rowspan="2">Metrics</th>
            <th style="width: 92px!important;" rowspan="2">Weightage</th>
            <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup">Target</th>
            <th style="width: 85px!important;" rowspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L1</th> 
            <th>L2</th>
            <th>L3</th>
            <th>L4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none;">
                <a class="plus" title="Plus" ><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                <a class="update" title="Update" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                <a class="destroy" title="Destroy"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
            </td>

            <td style="display: none;">
                <a class="add" title="Add" ><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                <a class="delete" title="Delete"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="button-bar">
<button class="btnn btnn--pill submit" id="Scoresubmit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!-- #/ container -->
</div>
```

## JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
    var menubar = $("table td:nth-last-child(2)").html();

    $(".add-heading").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();

        var row = '<tr class="heading">' +
        '<td id="HeadingLabelScorecard" colspan="3"><span id="label_hide" class="heading_label">Heading</span><input id="heading_label_input" class="heading_label-box" type="text" class="form-control"></td>' +
        '<td id="HeadingLabelScorecard" colspan="2"><span id="label_hide2" class="heading_weight-label">Total Weightage</span><input class="Tweightage" id="wei'+(wei) + '" type="number" ></td>' +
        '<td colspan="1"><span id="label_hide3" class="heading_labelCheckbox">Divide Weightage</span><input class="heading_checkbox" name="Dividecheckbox" id="heading_checkbox" type="checkbox">' +
        '<td style="text-align:center;">' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

        $("table").append(row);  
        $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        wei ++;
    });

    $(".add-point").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();  //TO ADD ROW AS LAST Child
        var lastCheckBox = $('[name="Dividecheckbox"]:last').prop("checked");   //get status of last checkbox
        if(lastCheckBox==false){
        //Enable row
        var row = '<tr class="Parameters" style="text-align: center;">' +
        '<td><input class="subpoint_label-box" type="text" class="form-control"id="metrics'+(unique_id) + '"></td>' +
        '<td><input disabled class="subpoint_weightage2"  id="weightage'+(unique_id) + '" type="number" ></td>' +
        '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="ex0n'+i+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="ex'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text"  id="ex1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
        '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="lx0n'+(i)+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="lx'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text" id="lx1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
        '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="zx0n'+(i)+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="zx'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text" id="zx1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
        '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="yx0n'+(i)+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="yx'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text" id="yx1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
        '<td width="20">' + menubar + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';            
}


        else if(lastCheckBox==true){
            var row = '<tr class="Parameters" style="text-align: center;">' +
            '<td width="20"height="50"><input class="subpoint_label-box" type="text" class="form-control"id="metrics'+(unique_id) + '"></td>' +
            '<td width="20"><input class="subpoint_weightage"  id="weightage'+(unique_id) + '" type="number" ></td>' +
            '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="ex0n'+i+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="ex'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text"  id="ex1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
            '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="lx0n'+(i)+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="lx'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text" id="lx1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
            '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="zx0n'+(i)+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="zx'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text" id="zx1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
            '<td><input class="slider_min-value" type="text" id="yx0n'+(i)+'" value="20"><b id="percentage">%</b><input class="subpoint-sbody" style="width: 120px;" name="n'+i+'" id="yx'+(unique_id) + '" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="[20,80]"/><input class="slider_max-value" type="text" id="yx1n'+(i)+'" value="80"><b id="percentageMax">%</b></td>' +
            '<td width="20">' + menubar + '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        }
        else{
            alert("Please Add Heading!!");
        }     
$("table").append(row);  
$("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".plus, .update").toggle();
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

$("#ex"+unique_id).slider({});
$("#ex"+unique_id).on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    var nid=$(this).attr('name');
    $("#ex0"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[0]);
    $("#ex1"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[1]);
});

$("#lx"+unique_id).slider({});
$("#lx"+unique_id).on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    var nid=$(this).attr('name');
    $("#lx0"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[0]);
    $("#lx1"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[1]);
});

$("#zx"+unique_id).slider({});
$("#zx"+unique_id).on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    var nid=$(this).attr('name');
    $("#zx0"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[0]);
    $("#zx1"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[1]);
});

$("#yx"+unique_id).slider({});
$("#yx"+unique_id).on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    var nid=$(this).attr('name');
    $("#yx0"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[0]);
    $("#yx1"+nid).val(slideEvt.value[1]);
});
unique_id++
i++      
});
```

## WHAT I TRIED TO GET THE DATA

```
$('#Scoresubmit').click(function () {
    GetCoScoreCard();
//ajax calll
});


function GetCoScoreCard() {

$('#scorecard_co .heading').each(function () { //tr 

    var TotalWeightage;
    var item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td');
$.each(item, function (key, value) {        //Heading

    if (key == 0) {
        Heading1 = ($(value).text());
        this.Heading1 = Heading1;
    }
    else if (key == 1) {
        TotalWeightage = ($(value).text());
    }
    else if (key == 2) {
        lastCheckBox = $('[name="Dividecheckbox"]:last').prop("checked");
    }
});


var parametername, param_Weightage;
$('#scorecard_co  .Parameters').each(function () { //td  //parameters
    var item2 = $(this).closest("tr").find('td');
    $.each(item2, function (key, value) {        
        datalist = ($(value).text());
        if (key == 0) {
            parametername = ($(value).text());
        }
        if (key == 1) {
            param_Weightage = ($(value).text());
        }


        if (key == 2 || key == 3 || key == 4 || key == 5)
        {
            var res = datalist.substring(1, 3);
            var res2 = datalist.substring(6, 8);
            var key1 = 'L' + i;
            MyLevels[key1] = res + "," + res2;
            i++;
        }
    });

    parameters = {
        "Name": parametername,
        "Weightage": param_Weightage,
"Levels": MyLevels,    //array
}

paramarray.push(parameters); //paramNewArray
MyLevels = {};
i = 0;
});

metrics={

    'Heading':Heading1,
'TotalWeitage': TotalWeightage,   //metrics heading and parameters
'DivideWeightage': lastCheckBox,
'parameters': paramarray          // paramNewArray
//work in process
}


var stringyfydata = JSON.stringify(metrics);
data1.push(stringyfydata); alert("Title=" + data1);
console.log(data1);
data = {};
parameters = {};
i = 0;
});
}
```

## EXPECTED DATA OUTPUT

```
 [
{"Heading":"SchduleAdherence","TotalWeitage":"20","DivideWeightage":true,"parameters":{"Name":"Scrunity","Weightage":"30","Levels":{"L1":"20,80","L2":"20,80","L3":"20,80","L4":"20,80"}}]},
{"Heading":"Attendence","TotalWeitage":"30","DivideWeightage":true,"parameters":{"Name":"self","Weightage":"30","Levels":{"L1":"20,80","L2":"20,80","L3":"20,80","L4":"20,80"}}]}

]
```

There are two classes (`.Heading` = to read the heading, e.g. attendance & another is `.Parameter` = to read the sub-points), my issue is that every time I try to loop through the data, all the parameters are getting added repeatedly in my object.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what data do you want to get from where? You posted a lot of code without really highlighting the critical sections that you need a help with.

Comment: @TomášZato . I've added some more information with screenshot at the begining of the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to re initialize your variable in go score code;

```
function GetCoScoreCard() {
    paramArray = [];
    data1 = [];
    .....
    .....
 }
```

Comment: As data1 is holding complete data which I need to pass to Ajax call.

Comment: data1 will be popoulated each time you called GetScoreCard so it will never be emoty and will always contain full data because each time you iterate over whole table rather than just new added items